# 'by viewModels()' Kotlin property delegate unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm trying to implement viewmodel with kotlin. First I added the needed dependecies:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
// Annotation processor
kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0"
```

Then I created a simple viewmodel:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val greeting = "Hello World"
}
```

But when I tried to access the view model from the activity with kotlin property delegate:

```
val model by viewModels<MyViewModel>()
```

The compiler does not resolve `viewModels`. I don't know what the problem is. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Add these dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
```

You can find the latest versions of libraries here:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment

Comment: fragment ktx should be enough afaik

Comment: @Pawel I just had a case where I already had fragment-ktx, but the error continued until I added activity-ktx.

Answer (score 18):

For me the solution above this not work.

I needed to import :

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
```

Comment: my biggest quest has been resolved now.

Answer (score 6):

**Resolved this error**, using below dependency in module-level **build.gradle**

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```

**OR**

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6'
```

I have also added below dependency to implement **ViewModel** in **Kotlin**

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
```

My module-level **build.gradle** start as per below

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It depends, on how you are using ViewModel. If you don't use fragments, this is enough to resolve  "Unresolved reference: viewModels" for activity.

```
// ViewModel
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.1'
```

```
// is to add the dependency on Fragment
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.5'
```

```
// is to add the dependency on Activity
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution above this not work.

Add this dependency: :

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
```

Add This dependency :

```
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycleviewmodel:2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was having the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.0'
```

but still I faced this same error.

The reason was that `by viewModels()` must be called inside the `onCreate()`:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val customViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                Surface() {
                    MyApp(customViewModel = customViewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and not in any other composable function. But I was trying to calling it from `MyApp()` composable function. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

See if you have ***navigation-fragment*** dependency added.

```
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.0")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.0")
```

Having this one and *activity/fragment-ktx* additionaly made *viewModels* delegate unavailable for me so I got rid of both of them and only left the navigation artifact.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was just using the wrong type of Activity. I had an `android.app.Activity` instead of an `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`.`viewModels()` is only available in the latter.